# How in angular ui / bootstrap set 100% height responsive?

Tags: angularjs, resize, angular-ui-bootstrap, responsive

i am using this lib: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and i need set my calculated height for panel-body to Accordion.

I have directive for parent div for $window resize event, but i need set height for child element on page load & resize.

How can i set custom height to element?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
angular.module(‘app’)
            .directive('calculateHeight', calculateHeight);

        function calculateHeight($window) {
            return function (scope, element) {
                var w = angular.element($window);
                scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
                    return { 'h': $window.outerHeight, 'w': $window.outerWidth };
                };
                scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                    scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
                    var matches = document.querySelectorAll(“div.panelBody”); // use selector to the element
                    matches[0].style.height = yourCustomHeight;
                }, true);

                w.bind('resize', function () {
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            };
        }
```